# Multiple cols class in Grid system not working in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5, where I am creating 6 columns when it is opened on desktop and wants to have 2 cols when opening on mobile, I followed the documents but it looks like the grid system is not working properly, all the 6 columns stacked and acting as rows. I used Bootstrap 3 version and it is working fine.

```
<div class='container border'>
<div class='row border'>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 border'> COl 1
</div>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 border'> COl 2
</div>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 border'> COl 3
</div>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 border'> COl 4
</div>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 border'> COl 5
</div>
<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 border'> COl 6
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: class col-xs-6 is not working, something has changed in bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it turned out there is no more col-xs since v4, so change to col-6 worked like a charm!

```
<div class='col-md-2 col-6 border'> COl 1
</div>
```